# Is there a way to force merge two excel tables with no common column? Using Python

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, associations, openpyxl

I have two excel files that I want to join their tables together but the problem is there isn't a common column to join them with.

For example generalized to get to the point:

file 1

| customer_id |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |

file 2

| purchase_id | purchase_amount |
| --- | --- |
| 501 | five |
| 502 | two |

I want it to look like this

| customer_id | purchase_id | purchase_amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 501 | five |
| 2 | 502 | two |

so far I have tried this but with no avail.

```
import pandas 

f1= pandas.read_excel(file1.xlsx)
f2= pandas.read_excel(file2.xlsx)

#merge file
f3=f1[["customer_id"]].merge(f2[["purchase_id", "purchase_amount"]])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for [`pd.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html):

```
import pandas as pd  # alias pandas

df1 = pd.read_excel('file1.xlsx')
df2 = pd.read_excel('file2.xlsx')

out = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)
print(out)

# Output
   customer_id  purchase_id purchase_amount
0            1          501            five
1            2          502             two
```